# ASP.NET MVC public alternative to UrlHelper.GenerateUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to embed a link to a controller action in my page so I can use it from javascript. Something like

```
var pollAction = '/Mycontroller/CheckStatus'
```

Now I am happy to hardcode it, but it would be really nice if there were a method I could use to create the URL. The AjaxHelper/HtmlExtensions contain methods to create hyperlinks (.ActionLink(...) and so on), but if you look into the guts of them, they rely on a method called UrlHelper.GenerateUrl() to resolve a controller and action into a url. This is internal so I can't really get at this.

Anyone found a good method in the framework to do this? Or must I roll my own?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried something along these lines?

```
var pollAction = '<%=Url.Action("CheckStatus", "MyController") %>';
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer out there! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If your page or control inherits from `ViewPage` or `ViewUserControl`, use the `Url.Action` method.

If not, use this instead:

```
 String url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath
              (
                ((MvcHandler) HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).RequestContext,
                new RouteValueDictionary
                (
                  new 
                  { 
                    controller = "MyController", 
                    action = "CheckState", 
                    id = idParameter 
                  }
                )
              ).VirtualPath;
```

Place this inside a method on your code-behind and call it from the HTML view.