# URL routing - opposite of GetRouteUrl in Asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

Assume I have the following defined in global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("about", "about", "~/About.aspx");
```

In an ashx file, I want to be able to pass in "about" and return "~/About.aspx".  I know the opposite can be done via GetRouteUrl, but is there a built-in function for what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to ask the opposite of what you have posted?  `GetRouteUrl` would be able to take an "about" parameter and return "~/About.aspx" already.  Do you mean you want to take a URL and find the route for it?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, GetRouteUrl will return "about", not "~/About.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [`RouteUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460347.aspx)?  Granted that method is part in the MVC assembly, it's an extension method so should be able to use it from WebForms (they share the same routing infrastructure).

Might also be interested in this question: [ASP.NET MVC public alternative to UrlHelper.GenerateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355700/asp-net-mvc-public-alternative-to-urlhelper-generateurl).  The answer that wasn't accepted might be more useful in your case.  It gets the URL from the [VirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.virtualpathdata.virtualpath.aspx) generated from your routes collection.