# MVC 4 Unauthorized access error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-error-pages, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, custom-error-handling

I'm trying to create custom error pages for a `MVC 4` application. But I can't seem to find proper reference material to learn about it.

I have a specific requirement. It's to do with `Unauthorized access` error. Say I have a set of pages which is only accessible to certain type of users. User typed `Admin` is authorized to access the admin page but the User typed `Basic` is not.

So what I want to do is, if the user who's type is `Basic` is logged into the website and if they try to visit the admin page, instead of throwing them to the login page show them a message in an error page.

Can anyone help me with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an exception filter?

```
 [HandleError(Exception = typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), View = "MyErrorPage")]
 public class MyController { }
```

I can't test this at the moment, if this doesn't work let me know and I'll create a custom filter for this purpose.

**UPDATE**

Since you've created your own custom attribute, you would pass information to your view from your attribute via `TempData`:

```
 public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
 {
     //Note you could assign a complex type here, let's just assign a string
     filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorDetails"] = "Here are my details"; 

     // Redirect to an "Unauthorized" controller
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Unauthorized"), true);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your answer, but it didn't work. I have a custom authorize attribute. so this unauthorized access error page should only show if the user is already logged in but not authorized to view the content. so I used a method mentioned in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355700/asp-net-mvc-public-alternative-to-urlhelper-generateurl  but, is it the best way to do it? How would I pass some helpful error message to the view.

Comment: sorry, the link should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles